# box-shadow не отображатся в мобильном устройстве

Tags: html, css

Форма регистарции, в настольных браузерах выглядит как и задумано, а на мобильном (сафари, хром) Не отображаются тени блока. Причем ниже кнопка с тенями, там все ок, а вот поля ввода выглядят не корректно.

[image: Так отображается]

[image: Так должно отображаться]

Это фрагмент верстки

```
        <form action="php/handlers/login.php" method="post">
            <p class="logout_title">Привіт, красуню!)</p><br>
            <input class="inp" type="text" name="auth_username" placeholder="логін">
            <input class="inp" type="text" name="password" placeholder="пароль">
            <div class="teeeest inp">uss</div>
            <input class="login_btn" type="submit" value="Увійти">
            <p>Не зареєстрована?<br>Звернись до <a target="blanc" href="https://t.me/marathon_TEST_bot">нашого бота</a></p>
        </form>
```

Это стили

```
:root {
  --neo_shadows:
    4px 4px 7px #0000001c,
    -4px -4px 4px #ffffff5e,
    4px 4px 7px #0000001c inset,
    -4px -4px 4px #ffffff5e inset;
}

#modal_auth_window form .inp {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: var(--text);
  box-shadow: var(--neo_shadows);
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: var(--main_bg);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: var(--borad);
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Причин может быть несколко:

1. Стоит проверить версию мобильных браузеров (могут не поддерживать данное свойство стилей)
2. проверить адаптивность. Возможно, что некоторые теги меняются или пересекаются стили

советую использовать конкретные стили теней как отдельный переиспользуемый добавочный уникальный класс. Назовите его, например .shadowed-input и пропишите без маршрута (#modal_auth_window form), скорее всего, браузер просто не отлавливает его и не может применить. Так же, без маршрута в стилях, позднее вы сможете повторно добавить этот класс к любому инпуту (или вовсе .shadowed-box назвать и применять везде, где нужен). Проверил на codepen, сработали стили только после того, как я убрал эту "изоляцию"

Comment: без полного файла стилей большего сказать не могу. Вероятно, Вы сами себя перемудрили при "верстке по бэму"

Comment: На счет адаптивности - сразу нет, тк сайт исключительно под мобильные и не имеет планшетной или десктопной точки слома. Может быть такое, что моб. браузер не поддерживает в одном css свойстве 4 значения?? Просто этой ошибки нет при "разборе" кода черз панель разработчика. Буду эксперементировать с кол-вом значений в одном свойстве сейчас

Comment: @4kilograms может быть, но только при условии старой версии. Новые версии браузера полностью поддерживают эти свойства и ошибки возникнуть не должно

Comment: В этом то и загвоздка, браузеры все последние, да и стилей там минимальн! https://debug.produktovy.shop/ Ежели будет минутка, гляньте. Тк искренне не понимаю чо может быть причиной(

Comment: странно, закинул в эту форму еще div с таким же классом, на нем отобразилис тени как положено, а на инпутах голяк!

Comment: А можете отредктировать вопрос, поместив туда всю форму? возможно, там где-то что-то конфликтует

Comment: отредактировал! Похоже мобильные браузеры режут стили для элементов пользовательского ввода!

Comment: Очень странно, потому что у меня на codepen ваша верстка отображается корректно (если убрать #modal_auth_window form, потому что он отсутствует в конкретном отрывке и мешает отображению).

Comment: замените .inp на input и тогда в конкретном модальном окне (с данным id, который использовать в других блоках нельзя) внутри тега form стили будут применяться к тегам input.

Comment: А для кнопки используйте специально придуманный тег <button>

Comment: Попробую, но что то мне подсказывает что это не решит проблему) как план Б попробую обернуть инпуты и уже оберткам применить стили)

Answer (score 0):

Решенеи было найдено! Как оказалось мобильные браузеры у элементов пользовательского ввода убирают некторые стили. По этому обернул оба нинпута в обертку, задав ей те самые преславутые тени. При этом сам инпут сделал с прозрачным фоном)

Вот как стало в верстке:

```
<div class="inp_wrapper">
  <input type="text" name="auth_username" placeholder="логін">
</div>
```

Вот как стало в стилях:

```
#modal_auth_window form .inp_wrapper {
  color: var(--text);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px #0000001c,
  -4px -4px 4px #ffffff5e,
  4px 4px 7px #0000001c inset,
  -4px -4px 4px #ffffff5e inset;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: var(--main_bg);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: var(--borad);
}

#modal_auth_window form input {
  border-radius: var(--borad);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Теперь все отображаетя именно так как требовала ситуаия) Надеюсь кому то поможет)